# How to only allow certain values as parameter for a method in Java?

Tags: java, android, methods, parameters, android-toast

I want to write a method that only takes certain values for a parameter, like f.e. in the `Toast` class in Android. You can only use `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` or `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` as duration for the method `makeText(Context context, int resId, int duration)`. I had a look at the source code of the `Toast` class but found nothing there. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You want to show toast for a certain time other than the one provided by FrameWork?

Comment: you can use Enum http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an [Enum Type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), from the Java Tutorial,

> An enum type is a special data type that enables for a variable to be a set of predefined constants. The variable must be equal to one of the values that have been predefined for it. Common examples include compass directions (values of NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, and WEST) and the days of the week.

As an example,

```
public enum MyEnum {
  ONE, TWO;
}

public static void myMethod(MyEnum a) {
  // a must be MyEnum.ONE or MyEnum.TWO (in this example)
}
```

**Edit**

To get String(s) from your enum types you can add field level values (which must be compile time constants) with something like,

```
public enum MyEnum {
  ONE("uno"), TWO("dos");
  MyEnum(String v) {
    value = v;
  }
  private String value;
  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: I want the parameters to be of a certain type, let's say string. How can I do that with Enums? Is that even possible?

Comment: @kaolick You can give your Enum(s) String values, but they must be Enum types (which are actually constants). Let me edit to give you an example.

Comment: @kaolick you want to give duration a custom value for the toast?

Comment: @Raghunandan No. I want my method to only accept certain fix values for a parameter.

Comment: @kaolick Then check the values to make sure they're allowable. You say "type", but you actually mean "value". You either need to use enums, types, or validate the values somehow.

Comment: @kaolick You can define a `ToastType` (or `ToastLength`) enum similar to Elliott's example, but saving an `int` and constructing the two enumerations with `int` values `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` and `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT`.  Now, have your methods use a `ToastType` argument instead of an `int` argument, and the methods can use `getValue()` to get the `int` when calling `makeText`.

Comment: @ajb I understand. But how does this work with int as parameter type in the `Toast` class?

Comment: @kaolick you will have to have a Custom Toast class. If you want the features from the framework copy the same and modify the way you want.

Comment: @Raghunandan It's not about the `Toast` class. It was just an example for a general problem.

Comment: @kaolick You'd need a wrapper class or a wrapper method, i.e. your own `makeText` method that uses a `ToastType` argument and turns around and calls `Toast.makeText`.  But if your aim is to prevent `Toast.makeText` from being called with illegal duration values, this will help accomplish that.

Comment: @ajb How can I do that? Can you give me an example? I want something like `myMethod(String myParam)` where I can use only certain values for myParam. I'd prefer that those would be final Strings in my class that contains `myMethod(String myParam)`. As I said, like in the `Toast` class. But maybe Google uses some other magic that we don't see here. ;-)

Comment: @kaolick If you're really set on using a `String` parameter, instead of defining another class (such as an `enum`) to represent the possible values, then this isn't going to work for you.  Your alternative is to have the method check for valid inputs and throw an exception if they're not.

Comment: @ajb You are right. But the solution using an Enum seems the better way because it cannot fail by throwing an Exception. Seems more safe though.

Answer (score 42):

You can use [@IntDef](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/IntDef.html) or [@StringDef](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/StringDef.html) annotations for your methods like this:

```
@Retention(SOURCE)
@IntDef({NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD, NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST, NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS})
public @interface NavigationMode {}
public static final int NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD = 0;
public static final int NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST = 1;
public static final int NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS = 2;
...
public abstract void setNavigationMode(@NavigationMode int mode);
@NavigationMode
public abstract int getNavigationMode();
```

Comment: the exact answer, should be accepted instead of the other one

Comment: @OmarElDon the question was asked for Android specifically so I provided answer for Android. You can see the tags  of the question.

Answer (score 1):

To use ints as is done with the Toast class, you can do something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    //by convention, constant names are all caps
    public static final int VALUE_ONE = 0;
    public static final int VALUE_TWO = 1;


    public void myMethod(int value) throws InvalidParameterException {
        if(value != VALUE_ONE || value != VALUE_TWO) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException();
            //or set default value instead of throwing an exception
        }
        else {
            //your code
        }
    }
}
```

`VALUE_ONE` and `VALUE_TWO` are static and final, meaning that throughout the entire application there will only be one instance of that variable, and its value will never change (if you know C, it is similar to a `#DEFINE`). Thus, when someone passes `MyClass.VALUE_ONE` as an argument, you know exactly what it is, every time, while the caller doesn't necessarily need to know the integer value behind the constant. And then you will want to do a runtime check to make sure that what was passed in was one of the valid values, and if not, throw an exception. Or, if the value passed in isn't very critical, you could just set a default value if the argument is incorrect rather than throw an exception.

Comment: I see. I hab something like that in mind but I was looking for a solution where I can avoid something like throwing an Exception. So I'm going with the Enum solution. But if someone wants to avoid using Enums, your solution seems correct.