# How to only allow certain int values as parameter for a method in Java?

Tags: java, android, methods, parameters, enums

Am creating method for library with two `int` `parameters` (min,max),
Method can accept ONLY the parameters if max value is bigger than the min value **on the run time** , means while the person is writing down the code if the parameter is not valid it shows warning before running the code, because i need to get `Random` number between both values.

what i have found from my search was this answer 
[How to only allow certain values as parameter for a method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715096/how-to-only-allow-certain-values-as-parameter-for-a-method-in-java)

however it seems like i cant get it working with int value.

Heres my code :

```
 public void call(int min, int max) throws InvalidParameterException {
        if (min == (int) min) {
            if (max == (int) max) {
                if (max <= min) {
                    throw new InvalidParameterException();
                } else {
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    // nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
                    // so add 1 to make it inclusive
                    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

                }

            } else {
                throw new InvalidParameterException();
            }
        } else {
            throw new InvalidParameterException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can consider generating a custom annotation and use Aspect for any method with matching annotation to apply it as a validation check.

Comment: So, what happens when you run it? It seems correct for me. What's wrong with it?

Comment: pretty much nothing happen i still can write down service.call(34,449); and it wont show any error or warning ( note: first number should be bigger) but it seems like InvalidParameterException is not getting triggered

Comment: Your second parameter is the max value and ofc does your method call cal(34,449) work. Because it's logically "correct". When you swap both values, you will get an InvalidParameterException. You can checkout my answer below.

Comment: i have tried both ways and no warnings even if its (10,3)

Comment: @HossamHassan. I have a note on your code; You don't print anything! So how will you know if it's working or not? Because the random might work or the exception may get thrown but you do not print anything to know. See Centos answer.

Comment: you are correct,but i want to show the warning before running the app, so when the person is calling the method and still writing down his code it shows warning without running, is theres way to do that or i have to run the method to get the warning ?

Comment: i have updated the question to be more clear that the warning need to pop up on the run time while writing down the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers mention normal validation of method parameters at runtime (aspects too), nothing special about this. The only thing to add is that you are doing a trick which is used when you have a floating point type and you want to check if it's equal to integer type, for example if `double == int`. Normally it's always gonna return `false`, that's why you cast double to int to perform actual check. There's no need for that in your code since you have only ints, `int == (int) int` is simply unnecessary.

The answer you linked tho, it mentions validation at compile-time by using enums - it's not possible here, you could create an enum with a lot of integer values, but please don't, unless your range of values is really limited.

Other option that comes to mind (since it's often used to perform 'magic' somewhere else than your code) is annotation processing, but I don't think it's actually possible for this use-case, definitely not in a standard way.

What you would need is some kind of source code analyzer. Something like Intellij/Eclipse plugin, [PMD](https://pmd.github.io), [Checker](https://checkerframework.org), or some other tool similar to those. It would analyze every occurrence of your method call and check if the first argument is smaller than the second one, if not then it wouldn't compile, you wouldn't even get as far as runtime. Definitely not worth the effort in this case, but this could be a good thing when you want to deal with this problem on a big scale, for example with Java nulls.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider generating a custom annotation and use Aspect for any method with matching annotation to apply it as a validation check.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface ValidateRange{
    Integer minValue();
    Integer maxValue();
}
```

The aspect can be something like this:

```
@Aspect
public class ValidateRangeAspect {

    @Before(value = "execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(ValidateRange)")
    public void validateRange(JoinPoint joinPoint, ValidateRange validateRange) {
       Integer minValue = validateRange.minValue();
       Integer maxValue = validateRange.maxValue();
       assertRange(getActualValueFromJoinPoint(), minValue, maxValue);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an example

Comment: Integer minValue() gives warning invalid type 'integer' for annotation member, and @Aspect connot be resolved

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
private static int getRandomIntValue(int min, int max) {

    if (min >= max) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("max must be greater than min");
    }

    Random r = new Random();
    return r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if I understand you correctly, but do you mean smth like this:

```
  public void call(int min, int max) throws InvalidParameterException {
if (max > min) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    // nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
    // so add 1 to make it inclusive
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
} else {
     throw new InvalidParameterException();
}
```

}

Comment: when i give the parameters to call method it doesnt show InvalidParameterException as i have just explained in comment above

Answer (score 1):

You can use google guava api and use it like this on your method.

```
public void call(int min, int max) {
  Preconditions.checkArgument(max > min);
  // Other code here
}
```

The method will throw IllegalArgumentException if the condition is not met.

Comment: Preconditions can be only called from within the same library group, do i need to use library for it ?

Comment: Yes, you will have to pull the library, if you are using Maven you can use .<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>21.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Or otherwise you can make your own check as illustrated in @Centos's answer, both options will work. fine.

Comment: ya his method is fine but sadly it wont trigger at runtime